# Is there a way that the user cannot modify the style in tradingview in the configuration options?

Tags: pine-script

When I use the plot () I see that in "configuration options" the user will be able to modify the style.

Is there a way that the user cannot modify the style in tradingview in the configuration options?

Is there a way that the user cannot see the style when I use plot()?

That is, I want to use the plot () but I don't want it to appear in the configuration options, I prefer the style to be my standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by setting the `editable` parameter of `plot()` to `false`.

```
plot(close, editable=false)
```

From the [reference manual for plot()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_plot):

> **editable (const bool)** If true then plot style will be editable in Format dialog. Default is true.